# Django ManyToMany Query intersection

Tags: python, django, database, many-to-many

I have the following model structure:

```
class Person(model.Models):
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group)

class Group(model.Models):
    pass

class Event(model.Models):
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group)
```

What I want to now do is get all `Event`s that contain a `Group` which a specific `Person` is in. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
Event.objects.filter(groups__person=person)
```